# How to ignore all news which are about my friends comments on stranger's photos on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments, photos, feeds

Very often I see my friends are commenting on their friends photos, statuses, etc., but I'm not interested if these interactions are not between my friends (if I don't know both of them).

How do I hide it from my news feed once and for all?

Answer (score 2):

Try [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/)... it lets you block all sorts of things. I don't know if it blocks exactly what you're asking for, but it supports regexes, so perhaps you can come up with one to block what you need.